# How to handle Salesforce Heapsize limit

Tags: apex

We are building a sync service for downloading all the objects data via a single call. 
If all the data excceed 20000 records, when we use

```
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueof(JSON.serialize(syncServiceInstance)));
```

It will show the Heapsize exceed error.
How to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

Really, the only thing you can do is try to reduce the heap size.

You could try to construct the JSON string in batches of records instead of passing the whole List.  It might looks something like this:

```
String s = '';
for(List<My_Object__c> objList : [SELECT ... FROM MY_Object__c]){
   //add serialized list (remove outer {})
   s += StringJSON.serialize(objList).substring(1,s.size()-1);
}
return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueof(s));
```

After each loop the objects in `objList` should be garbage collected.

Another way would be to implement paging in your service (assuming you mean a web-service) and only pull down so many records at a time.

Finally, if syncServiceInstance is a list of `SObject`, then I would recommend just using the [Bulk Data API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/).  It will be way faster and save you from a hacky implementation.